# mongodb error while executing aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

I would appreciate your help and comments over this. I have been running mongodb without any issues.

I am doing a large aggregation and after a while I am getting the following error:

> com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 8
>   (UnknownError): 'assertion src/mongo/db/pipeline/value.cpp:1365' on
>   server mongo1:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" :
>   "assertion src/mongo/db/pipeline/value.cpp:1365", "code" : 8,
>   "codeName" : "UnknownError" }

the query being executed i similar to :

```
db.getCollection('saft_documents').aggregate([
    { 
       $match:{invoiceDate: {$gte: new ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), $lte: new ISODate("2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z")}}
    },
    {
       $unwind:"$lines"
    },
    {
       $group:{
               _id:{taxEntity:"$taxEntity",invoiceType:"$invoiceType",invoiceStatus:"$invoiceStatus", productCode:"$lines.productCode",productDesc:"$lines.productDescription"},
               numberOfLines:{$sum:1},
               quantity:{$sum:"$lines.quantity"},
               creditAmount:{$sum:"$lines.creditAmount"},
               debitAmount:{$sum:"$lines.debitAmount"},
               taxPayableRec:{ 
                 $sum:{  $cond: [ 
                         {$ifNull: ['$lines.taxBase', false]},
                         {$multiply:["$lines.taxBase",{$divide:["$lines.taxPercentage",100]}]}, 
                         {$multiply:[{$subtract:["$lines.creditAmount","$lines.debitAmount"]} ,{$divide:["$lines.taxPercentage",100]}]}
                     ] }
                  }
           }
    },
    {
       $project:{
              _id:0,
              taxEntity: "$_id.taxEntity",
              invoiceType: "$_id.invoiceType",
              invoiceStatus: "$_id.invoiceStatus",
              productCode: "$_id.productCode",
              productDesc: "$_id.productDesc",
              numberOfLines:1,
              quantity:1,
              creditAmount:1,
              debitAmount:1,
              taxPayableRec:1,
              netTotal: {$subtract:["$creditAmount","$debitAmount"]},
              grossTotal: {$add:[{$subtract:["$creditAmount","$debitAmount"]},"$taxPayableRec"]}
           }  
    }

// uncomment to show the number of groups generated    
//     ,{
//     $group:{
//         _id:null,
//         count:{$sum:1}
//         }}

 ],{ allowDiskUse: true })
```

Have you crossed accross this error already? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to to post the code/query that you have tried in order to get help and visibility. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what is your query?